# Spaces in paths in batch mode R

Tags: r, batch-file

I'm trying to get an R script to run from a batch file so it can be nice and clean for other users. Currently, you drag and drop a CSV file onto the batch file and it passes the file name to the R script for input.

When there's a space in the file path/name it works fine in RStudio but causes problems when I call it from the batch file. When I do that it tries to open the path before the space.

I've tried to reformat the file path from within R by using `shortPathName(inputPath)` and by replacing spaces with "\ " but it doesn't seem to work.

At the moment, the script is launched with

```
    "%~dp0\R-3.6.0\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "--args %~1" "%~dp0\Script.R"
```

with the script containing

```
    args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
    inputPath <- args[1]
    inputPath <- shortPathName(inputPath)
    inputData <- read.csv(inputPath)
```

It runs fine from within RStudio but crashes when launched from the batch producing this error message in the output file:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>   Calls: read.csv -> read.table -> file
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, "rt") :
>     cannot open file '*file path up to the space*': No such file or directory
>   Execution halted

Answer (score 0):

By no means a R expert, but I'd try

```
%~dp0\R-3.6.0\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "--args %~s1" "%~dp0\Script.R"
```

The `%~s1` should supply the short filename as the argument.

Comment: Ah yes thank you, it was pretty close to that! Turns out it was my placement of the "" that was causing the batch file to have a problem with the spaces. I thought putting them around the whole `--args` would do the trick, but that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several formulations of the batch file and some debugging, I found that the batch file was passing the first part of the file before the space as the first argument.

After finding that the use of R in CMD BATCH mode is no longer advisable so switched to running using Rscript mode as

```
    "%~dp0\R-3.6.0\bin\Rscript.exe" --vanilla "%~dp0\Script.R" "%~1"
```

This allowed for the argument to be passed to R with "", and hence with the space.
Since v3.5.1, R accepts file paths with spaces.